# Drawing text, callouts, rectangles, etc in QGIS

Tags: qgis, text, toolbar, map-drawing

In ArcGIS Desktop, you have a specific toolbar for adding text/ drawing rectangles, circles, ... / adding callouts (see screenshot), which I use very regularly.
However, I am switching to QGIS 3.4, since it's free and easy to use. I wonder if there is a similar toolbar in QGIS, like the one in ArcGIS Desktop, because I haven't found it up until now. There are a lot of different plugins that do the job, but it's more complicated than the simple toolbar in ArcGIS Desktop.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The [Annotation Toolset](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html#annotation-tools) allows you to add callouts to the *map canvas*. A callout can have text, an SVG image, a form with information from a vector layer attribute table, or HTML.

[image] Image source: [QGIS User Manual](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html#annotation-tools)

QGIS uses the [print layout](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/print_composer/index.html) interface for printing or exporting maps. The print layout provides a wide variety of ways to manipulate the export without changing the underlying map. (The print layout was called print composer in earlier versions of QGIS - many tutorials use the terms interchangeably.)

You can [add shapes](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/print_composer/composer_items/composer_items_shape.html) to the print layout. The shapes will appear in any map you print or export from that print layout, but they will not appear in the map canvas.

If you *need* to add shapes to the map canvas, manipulate the layer symbology or add them as a layer. Neither of these methods is as convenient as the toolbar in Arc, because most of the reasons you would want to add shapes that aren't part of a data layer are covered by one of the other features in QGIS. There are several plugins that will make it easy to add specific shapes to a polygon layer, eg [Shape Tools](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/shapetools/). To install a plugin, go to the Plugin menu > Manage and Install Plugins.